# Does vim have a motion that does nothing?

Tags: vim

When reformatting text with the 'gq' or 'gw' commands, I usually work on the whole paragraph, so the accompanying motion is 'ap'. Sometimes, however, I want to reformat only a few lines ('gw3k' for example) and sometimes only one line.

For the last problem, "gwl" or "gwh" work, as they stay on the same line, but they're not quite intuitive. Ideally, I'd like to use a motion that does nothing, i.e. has the cursor stand still. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Vim commands handle single-line operations as special cases, usually by repeating the keystroke. Examples are `dd`, `yy`, `cc`, etc.

Thus the opperations to reformat the current line are `gqq` or `gww`.

Given this convention, I'm not sure of a use for a "null" motion.

Comment: Well, there's still stuff like 'gul' and 'gUl', but probably I'm only misguided by the blocky shape of the cursor in that case.

Comment: There's always `~` to toggle the case of an individual letter.